# Meteor: Global object not updating

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am using Ionic 2 with meteor/MongoDB.

When I do the following, it `inserts` the `chat` object into the `localChatCollection`:

```
      let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = this.findChats();
      promise.then((data: Mongo.Collection<Chat>) => {

        let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
        data.find().forEach(function (chat: Chat) {
          console.log('==> ' + chat);
          localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        });
```

However, if I define the `localChatCollection` globally, it does not `insert` the `chat` object. There are no errors but the process just stops on the `insert` line.

```
private localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
....
         this.localChatCollection.insert(chat);
```

Any ideas how I can get this to insert into a globally defined `collection`?

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I don't think it is the most elegant solution:

```
        let that = this;
        data.find().forEach(function (chat: Chat) {
          that.localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        });
```